# Using CodeIgniters Upload class, trying to put select data in a new array for DB stor

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

am trying to use CodeIgners Upload class to get info from a successfully uploaded image (file_name, image_size_str). i want to put this select data into a new array so i can then store in a DB table. the code fails when using foreach to cycle thru the data, to  try and put into a new array using array_push. I have to fail commented.

```
function do_upload(){
$dbImgInfoStore = array();  
$this->load->model('upload_model');
$config['upload_path']='./uploads/';
$config['allowed_types']='gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size']='10000'; //etc, etc
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
    $error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
    $this->load->view('upload_form',$error);
} else {
    $data = array('upload_data'=>$this->upload->data());
    // NOT WORKING EITHER! 
    foreach($data as $key=>$value) {
        if($key == 'image_size_str') {
            array_push($dbImgInfoStore, $dbImgInfoStore['image_size_str']=$value);
        } elseif ($key == 'file_name') {
            array_push($dbImgInfoStore, $dbImgInfoStore['file_name']=$value);
        }
    } 
    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);

}
}
```

strangely, when sending to a new page

```
$this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
```

i'm able to do exactly what i'm trying to do a few lines earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access `$data['upload_data']` in the `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($data['upload_data'] as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'image_size_str') {
       $dbImgInfoStore['image_size_str'] = $value;
    } 
    elseif ($key == 'file_name') {
       $dbImgInfoStore['file_name'] = $value;
    }
}
```